# Ionic how to pass a variable to controller from tab

Tags: variables, ionic-framework

i have this structure, a classic tab in ionic:

```
 .state('tab.comments', {url: "/diary", 
                        views: {'tab-diary': 
                        {templateUrl: "tab-diary.html", 
                        controller: 'DiaryCtrl'}
                        }
})
.state('tab.comments', {url: "/comments", 
                        views: {'tab-diary': 
                        {templateUrl: "tab-comments.html", 
                        controller: 'CommentsCtrl'}
                        }
})
```

Then i have a jQuery.Ajax that populate a div in tab-diary.html... here are a list of post each one with a link to the comments page.

The comment page is nested into diary.

I call the comment page with:

```
<a class="tab-item dark" href="#/tab/comments>GO TO COMMENTS</a>
```

In the comments page i want to get the post id, but i don't know how to pass ad request the variable...

Please help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add a parameter in the state url

```
.state('tab.comments',
      {url: "/comments/:id", 
      views: {
             'tab-diary': 
                {
                   templateUrl: "tab-comments.html", 
                   controller: 'CommentsCtrl'}
                }
```

})

and then add the id to the end of the href like this

```
<a class="tab-item dark" href="#/tab/comments/{{id}}">GO TO COMMENTS</a>
```

and in the controller you can get the id using $stateParams

```
var id = $stateParams.id;
```

Comment: Perfect it works!! I was missing to use $stateParams! THANK YOU!